# Why declaring a variable outside a function and assigning a value in a loop uses more memory than a local var?

Tags: javascript, memory, garbage-collection

I am doing 2 simple tests and profiling them in the google devtools timeline.
Declaring a variable outside the function and assigning it a new value in a for loop seems to allocate lots of memory and triggers the garbage collector repeatedly.
On the other hand, declaring the variable in the scope of the function allocates less memory or no memory at all.
Here is the first case:

```js
(function() {
  function createVars() {
    var i;
    var b;
    for (i = 0; i < 10000; i += 1) {
      b = Math.random();
    }
    requestAnimationFrame(createVars);
  };

  requestAnimationFrame(createVars);
}())
```

[image: case 1]

And the second one:

```js
(function() {
  var b;

  function createVars() {
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < 10000; i += 1) {
      b = Math.random();
    }
    requestAnimationFrame(createVars);
  };

  requestAnimationFrame(createVars);
}())
```

[image: case 2]
I would have expected the opposite or at least a similar behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Possible explanation: Local variables are stored on the *stack*, and after each execution of the function, that contains them, are deleted. Global variables, defined outside the function, are defined on the *heap*, and continue to exist after each execution. Moreover, on each execution a new variable is created, accumulating more used memory.

Comment: what do you mean by a new pair is created?

Comment: a new variable `var b;` is created

Comment: But that's the issue. On the second case, the "b" var is created only once, not on each execution, and it accumulates more memory.
The first part of your answer may be the answer.

Comment: Then it must be related to the fact that when you pass a result _by value_  it is _copied_. In contrast, when you _pass-by-reference_, it is not.

Answer (score 0):

First case, you create a 'b' variable each time you call 'createVars'.
Second case, you use only one variable. Always the same. :)

Comment: That's the point. I'm creating a new variable each time but it seems to allocate less memory. Shouldn't it be the other way around?

Comment: But in your first graph the memory usage is larger no ? It increase infinitely!
EDIT: Heap size also depends of the number of calls to 'createVars'. So if you run your test longer the heap size increase...

Comment: Actually, it is smaller and that's why the garbage collector isn't triggered. The second graph grows faster and GC is happening around every 10 frames.
Eventually, the second graph will trigger GC and reset as well.

Comment: When I run them on my computer: the first reach more than 25 millions and increase and the second reach 21 millions and return to a lower value... The only thing I don't understand, why the first is so slowly increasing...